# Missing entry in flagging history

Tags: support, spam, flag-history

I happened to glance upon my flagging history and I realized that there was an entry missing from the *spam* section in it. I had marked *6 posts as spam*, out of which *4 were deemed helpful* and *1 was declined*. I'm not sure what happened to the remaining 1 entry and why it is missing from the history summary. Here is a snapshot of the spam section of my flagging history.

[image: Spam section of flagging history]

Is this behavior a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

*Note:* I've checked my flagging history completely and there is no spam flag which is still in the *active* state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have one spam flag that was dismissed as disputed. Unfortunately there is no counter for disputed flags on spam and offensive at the moment. It's pretty rare that those flags get marked in such a way.

The moderator that reviewed the flag opted to clear the spam/offensive flags from the post, which removes the effects of them (the implicit downvote) and apparently dismisses any active spam/offensive flags as "disputed" as well.

Comment: But shouldn't it show as entry in the list itself?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I've reproduced this on several profiles. The disputed counter only appears in the list for regular moderator attention flags. For some reason it's never shown for spam/offensive flags.

Comment: But OP says "I've checked my flagging history completely" and he doesn't see 6 flags - does it mean disputed spam flag just vanish into thin air?

Comment: In that case, shouldn't this flag(with the status *disputed*) be available in my flagging history, atleast?

Comment: @RJ It appears on Page 6 of your flagging history. If it's not showing to you, then it's possible that it's being hidden, but it is perfectly visible to me.

Comment: @animuson - Yeah I can see that now. May be it missed by eyes, as I was hunting for the bright orange *active* thinking that some flag might still be in *active* state. It just struck me, that I hadn't looked at *disputed* case. Thanks! :)

Comment: @R.J Not that I know of. Was just throwing it out there in case you really couldn't see it.