# Spam flag count doesn't add up

Tags: discussion, flags

I was just looking at my flagging history to see what was pending and just happened to notice that the spam flag count doesn't appear to add up.

Why would *deemed helpful* + *declined* != *posts marked spam*?

There are no disputed flags listed, and it is only a difference of one, but still I'm curious as to what that one is...

Comment: Do you have disputed spam flags as well?

Comment: @juergend nope - no disputed listed... I've updated question based on your comment... I was under the impression spam flags couldn't be disputed as they're mod attention only, so thus would be purely helpful/declined...

Comment: Any "disupted" (not sure about declined) spam flags show up in the total count, but don't get their own row. So you would see `1 post marked spam, 1 helpful`.

Comment: @juergend: I'm with Jon in that I'm pretty sure spam flags can't be "disputed".

Comment: @Matt Uh... [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kDPZH.png) is what I see in my flag history.

Comment: @hichris123 that's confused me a bit more... does your total make sense though?

Comment: @JonClements Nope, I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sWw2g.png) (24 flagged, 23 helpful).

Comment: Hmmm.... let me see if I can find a disputed spam flag then

Comment: @hichris123: In which case I stand corrected :P. [Here's a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207169/missing-entry-in-flagging-history) which explains how a spam post can be disputed. This question also seems to be a duplicate of it (assuming Jon can find a disputed spam flag).

Comment: @Matt yup... found a disputed spam flag (which I didn't think was possible) - so learnt something new today... Perfectly happy this is a dupe of [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207169/missing-entry-in-flagging-history)

Comment: The link Matt presented is exactly what happened here. You had one disputed spam flag (which was oddly disputed by Community, despite other spam flags on that post being marked helpful by a moderator). Can't quite explain that one, but it doesn't hurt you in any way.

Comment: @BradLarson yup... not concerned about it at all - just one of those things that was niggling me... thanks for looking into it though... please feel free to close as dupe :)