# Disputed flags count for spam, offensive and comments flags missing in flagging history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flag-history, disputed-flags

In the flag summary page, the flagging history shows the disputed flags count for moderator attention flags but not for spam, offensive and comments flags.

[image]

I request the community to show that count for those flag types too.

Comment: Related(may be): http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207169/216721 :)

Comment: Afaik comment flags cannot get dismissed as disputed, so there's no need for a count there as it would always be zero.

Comment: @animuson, oh I don't know about that. But, the spam and offensive flags can get disputed. So, we can show those numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This was implemented in the latest build to help clarify the flag history a bit. You will now see declined, disputed, waiting for review, aged away on any flag where that status might apply.  As [animuson pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230173/disputed-flags-count-for-spam-offensive-and-comments-flags-missing-in-flagging#comment756014_230173) there is no disputed on comments so that wouldn't appear.  The stats will now look like:

> [image]